# How does pass-by-reference work?

Tags: pass-by-reference, pascal

Pass-by-reference is easy to visualize with languages that use pointers mostly. But in Pascal, I can hardly see how the pointers pass around subroutines as arguments.

For example:

```
var a: array [0..2] of integer;
    i : integer;

    procedure swap(var x, y: integer);
    var temp: integer;
    begin
       temp := x;
       x := y;
       y := temp;
    end;

begin
    i := 0;
    a[i] := 2;
    swap(i, a[i]);
end.
```

Can the `swap(i, a[i]);` procedural call statement be replaced with this equivalent pseudocode? Is this how interpreters work behind the scenes?

```
var tmpOldArrayExpression, tmpNewFirst, tmpNewSecond : integer;
tmpOldArrayExpression := i;
(tmpNewFst, tmpNewSnd) := swap(i, a[i]);
i := tmpNewFirst; { 2 }
a[tmpOldArrayEession] := tmpNewSecond; { 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes, the function `Swap` is *implemented* as:

```
function Swap(x, y: ^integer); // or: PInteger
var
  temp: integer;
begin
  temp := x^;
  x^ := y^;
  y^ := temp;
end;
```

And it is in reality (but not syntactically) called like:

```
i := 0;
a[i] := 2;
swap(@i, @a[i]);
```

And Pascal is a **compiled** language. It is (generally) not interpreted.

---

*To read more about this, read [my article explaining pointers and references, especially about reference parameters](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html#refparams). It is about Delphi, but the same principles apply to most Pascals.*

Comment: Your helpful link answer most of my pascal problems. Could you please anwser me one more question? For interperters that don't compile to machinecode on the fly (JIT), do they work behind the scene similar to my pseudocode?

Comment: If you have another question, then ask another one. There have been entire books (with many many pages) written on how interpreters (and/or compilers) work. I have no idea what you mean with "similar to my pseudocode".

Comment: It's the initial question of this topic, I don't think I should  make a new duplicate one. What do you mean by "C#"?

Comment: Typo. Cancelled the comment and wrote a new one.

Comment: FWIW, I assume interpreters do this the same way as Pascal, if they support pass-by-reference. They certainly don't do what your pseudo-code does.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik Pascal is even simpler than C in this regard, because while yes it has separate syntax, but there are no rules about parameters being aliases of each other (which IIRC C does have)